# Is bounty really needed for non accepting answered questions?

Tags: discussion

I am asking few questions in Stack Overflow. But till now I am not satisfied with the answers. So I do not accept anything. Today I saw the warning below:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this
>   question?

Is bounty really needed for non accepting answered questions?

Comment: You've said it yourself - you're not satisfied with the answers so putting up a bounty is *exactly* what you should be doing to try to attract better answers that *do* satisfy you.

Comment: @ChrisF Why not post that as an answer? :)

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question? ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer - I see what you did there...

Answer (score 9):

You've said it yourself - you're not satisfied with the answers so putting up a bounty is *exactly* what you should be doing to try to attract better answers that *do* satisfy you.

If one of the answers *does* provide a satisfactory answer then you *should* accept that. If several of the answers provided clues to the ultimate solution, then you should post that yourself (with proper attribution) and self accept. Self acceptance doesn't confer any reputation, but does show other users that your problem is solved *to your satisfaction*.

It's the way the system is designed and it appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Without a bounty you might get lucky and find someone subscribed to the tag was thinking about posting a really awesome answer a few days later, or you might find someone trawls through old unanswered questions in a month or two. This tends to happen more in some tags than other tags though in my experience.

If you really care right now though then a bounty is the way to encourage people to pay more attention to it. It's basically an advert for your question.